# How to get Id of an User to viewmodel? [login form]

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

so i'm working on this project.
basically i'm trying to make a login form.
and i need to get id that is inside the table 'users', but i dont know how?
can someone show me how its done?

i have tried changing it from bool to int and returning id.

```
create table users(
id int not null auto_increment,
FirstName varchar(255),
LastName varchar(255),
isTeacher bool,
TeachingSubject varchar(255),
loginUsername varchar(12),
loginPassword varchar(12),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);



public bool LoginUser(LoginViewmodel userLogin)
    {
            var cmdCommand = "select count(1) from users WHERE loginUsername=@LOGINUSER AND loginPassword=@LOGINPASS;";
            OpenConnection();
            MySqlCommand loginCommand = new MySqlCommand(cmdCommand, studentsConnection);
            loginCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOGINUSER", userLogin.LoginUsername);
            loginCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOGINPASS", userLogin.LoginPassword);
            var test = Convert.ToInt32(loginCommand.ExecuteScalar());
            userLogin.Id = test;
            Console.WriteLine(userLogin.Id);
            CloseConnection();
            if (test == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new BadLoginCredentialsException();
            }
        }




    public class LoginViewmodel
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public bool isTeacher { get; set; }
    public string TeachingSubject { get; set; }
    public string LoginUsername { get; set; }
    public string LoginPassword { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    }





public WorkList()
    {
        LoginViewmodel userLogin = new LoginViewmodel();
        //loginUserId = 1;
        lblUserId.Text = userLogin.Id.ToString(); // i need to put the id into a label here
        }
```

it needs to write the users id to a viewmodel, so that i could use them in my other forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try. Since `COUNT(1)` will return the number of matches, if there are no duplicates you will always get either 1 or 0. You want the actual Id of the user.

Change the return type to `int` instead of `bool` and change `count(1)` to the actual column name for the user id, then you return that value.

```
public int LoginUser(LoginViewmodel userLogin)
    {
            var cmdCommand = "select userIdColumnName from users WHERE loginUsername=@LOGINUSER AND loginPassword=@LOGINPASS;";
            OpenConnection();
            MySqlCommand loginCommand = new MySqlCommand(cmdCommand, studentsConnection);
            loginCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOGINUSER", userLogin.LoginUsername);
            loginCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOGINPASS", userLogin.LoginPassword);
            var test = Convert.ToInt32(loginCommand.ExecuteScalar());
            userLogin.Id = test;
            Console.WriteLine(userLogin.Id);
            CloseConnection();
            if (test > 0)
            {
                return test;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0
            }
        }
```

Notice the change in the return

```
if (test > 0)
                {
                    return test;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0
                }
```

As long as no user has 0 as userId, this might solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work, but how do i get it to my main form?
LoginViewmodel users = new LoginViewmodel();
lblUserId.Text = Convert.ToString(users.Id); // this gives me a problem that **lblUserId** was null. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I think you need something like this approach `lblUserId.Text = users.Id.ToString()`

Comment: The routine `LoginUser(LoginViewmodel userLogin)` returns the actual UserId. So this might be the solution `lblUserId.Text  = LoginUser(LoginViewmodel userLogin)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the 'count(1)' in the select statement is, surely this needs to be 'id' if your hoping to receive an ID from a record where the '@LOGINUSER' and '@LOGINPASS' match the ones given.

Comment: yes see this is the problem, i dont have id, i have login form with 2 text boxes one is loginUsername other is loginPassword so i must use them to get the ID of the user and by ID i need to be able to get Firstname, lastname... etc. so what should i replace count(1) with?

Comment: if you want to get all the fields from a certain record, use the character '*' instead of 'count(1)'. Also, your 'id' field within your database is an auto-increment, so a value will be produced once a record is added so the records do have an 'ID' within the database. To get this id, simply change your 'cmdCommand' statement to     'select id from users WHERE loginUsername=@LOGINUSER AND loginPassword=@LOGINPASS'

Answer (score 0):

First change your SQL you use in your method. If you count the lines you can't get the user ID(Atleast I don't think you can)
So make your SQL like this :

```
"select * from users WHERE loginUsername=@LOGINUSER AND loginPassword=@LOGINPASS";
```

change your MySqlCommand with

```
MySqlDataAdapter dtReader = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdCommand, con);
//con is your connection ofc
```

after that you can retrieve your returning value like this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dtReader.Fill(dt);
```

then its easy you just make a for loop in dt.Rows and with dt.Rows.Count you can count if you want to.

Once you have get the correct information from SQL you have 2 options you can change your returning type of method or you can out the value with OUT parameter in method.
For out you have to change your method like this :

```
 public bool LoginUser(LoginViewmodel userLogin, out string UserId)
        {
            var cmdCommand = "select count(1) from users WHERE loginUsername=@LOGINUSER AND loginPassword=@LOGINPASS;";
            OpenConnection();
            MySqlDataAdapter dtReader = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdCommand, con);
            dtReader.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOGINUSER", userLogin.LoginUsername);
            dtReader.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOGINPASS", userLogin.LoginPassword);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dtReader.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                UserId = dt.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new BadLoginCredentialsException();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `UserId = dt.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString();` Wont exists as there will only be a count.

Comment: I've changed my SQL command, now it will return the whole line and the OP can just pick the Id column inside of it, or OP can change the * with Id column directly if OP does not require other columns